# change location to preset coordinates and zoom with click of a button

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a side panel for my google maps api v3 web app and I would like to add the capability to change to a predefined location and zoom when clicking a button. I am thinking javascript is the answer I am just not certain how to implement. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a code snippet:

```
<script>
function ZoomAndCenter() {
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644));
  map.setZoom(15);
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:ZoomAndCenter()">Move to location</a>
```