# Animate zoom to google map location on click(custom google maps controls)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to have google map displaying whole planet(zoomed out maximally). Then, I would like to put overlay over map with button. When user click on button the overlay is removed and google map is automatically animating to the location i want.

So, I am not asking for complete solution, I just want you to tell me if it's possible to do that using google map js api, and if you can give me some direction, that would be awesome. I have searched a lot but found nothing on this subject.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed, that if difference between current zoom level and new zoom level more that 2, google maps won't make smooth zooming.

You can take a look at same question: [How to zoom in smoothly on a marker in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752340/how-to-zoom-in-smoothly-on-a-marker-in-google-maps)

Comment: I've notice that too. Thanks for the link but I didn't find it aplicable to my situation.

Answer (score -1):

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(theLatitude, theLongitude));
map.setZoom(yourZoomLevel);
```

See also: [change location to preset coordinates and zoom with click of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367808/change-location-to-preset-coordinates-and-zoom-with-click-of-a-button)

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: doesn't it just set the center and zoom level the normal way?